# "Is not mapped" expection with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have created a simple Hibernate test app but for some reason the ReciepeModel is not mapped. I have defined it in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. I have checked that I have the proper imports `import javax.persistence.*;`

Here's the exception when trying to run the program:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ReciepeModel is not mapped [FROM ReciepeModel WHERE idreciepe = :id]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907)
    at com.calicode.connection.Connector$1.process(Connector.java:16)
    at com.calicode.connection.ConnectionTemplate.createSession(ConnectionTemplate.java:24)
    at com.calicode.connection.Connector.connect(Connector.java:20)
    at com.calicode.connection.Connector.main(Connector.java:9)
```

I have created the following ReciepeModel which is mapped in the configuration file:

```
package com.calicode.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "reciepe")
public class ReciepeModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idreciepe")
    private int idreciepe;
}
```

Here's hibernate.cfg.xml with ReciepeModel mapped:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <mapping class="com.calicode.model.ReciepeModel"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here's a simple test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        connect();
    }

    public static void connect() {
        new ConnectionTemplate() {
            @Override
            public void process(Session session) {
                Query query = session.createQuery("FROM ReciepeModel WHERE idreciepe = :id");
                query.setParameter("id", 1);
            }
        }.createSession();
    }
```

I have run out of ideas as to why this is not working. After going through other questions of the same topic, I feel like there's something bigger broken here.

**EDIT 1** Added the package name to ReciepeModel code snippet

Comment: What is the package name of class `ReciepeModel`? Show its original line of source code: `package ... `

Comment: @Andremoniy the ReciepeModel's package is `com.calicode.model`

Comment: May be you have several hibernate cfg files? E.g. one for production, one for tests?

Comment: Only one `hibernate.cfg.xml` is present in the project

Comment: +1 to the question, because I will be surprised if somebody will found the decision except my idea about broken configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by changing the Gradle dependency `'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final'` to `'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.3.RELEASE'`.

This is fine because I will be using Spring Boot in this project anways.